# How can I make one side of a rectangle angled like an arrow?

Tags: beamer, diagrams

I want to draw this diagram. But can't find a way to draw this box with sloped sides like an arrow.

[image: diagram]

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  A good start is to start with the documentation for the given drawing packages and the examples included.

Answer (score 10):

You could use the `signal` shape from the tikz `shapes` libary.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw=blue,fill=blue,shape=signal,signal to=east,text=white]{bla};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

One alternative is to use an arrow where the arrow head does not extend.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[shape=single arrow,
  single arrow head extend=0pt,
  single arrow tip angle=120,
  fill=gray,text=white,inner sep=8mm]{Security building};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]